# .xlsm file open as read-only

Tags: excel, vba

No doubt a very easy fix that someone here has come across before...

I have an Excel macro enabled file (.xlsm) that has some VBA to make graphs, pick data, get data, scale axes etcetera however 75% of the time when I open the file it says that another user has the file open and will be read only.

I've checked very carefully and I'm definitely the only user with the file open. The same thing occurs if the file is located either on the hard drive of this computer or if I load it from a server.

If the file is saved as a .xls file the problem never occurs, up to date at least.

Adding "End" to the VBA code seemingly has no effect.

I can only assume from my above tests that it is something in the VBA part of the file that causes this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These are Excel settings for the computer. If you go to the File tab on the ribbon, Excel options and go to Trust Center > Trust Center Settings you can modify this.

You can set the trusted locations documents or publishers.  Also check macro settings and protection.

Answer (score 0):

Some thought:

1) Check your code to see if at any point, you have the file open (workbook.open to current file)
2) Is the file on a network?
3) Check the .xlsm's properity if it is read-only
4) Go to Option - Trust Center - Trust Center setting to see if macro is enabled.